# Understanding the use of brackets in set theory notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would appreciate help understanding the presence and absence of brackets in this particular example, which hopefully will clarify things for me.

It is a line from a short proof by contradiction based on the Axiom of Foundation that No Set is an Element of Itself.

Why are there brackets on some $S$'s and not on others.

> > Suppose $S\in S$. Let $T=\{S\}$, then $T\bigcap S=\{S\}$, etc.

Thanks

Comment: $S$ is a set, $\left\lbrace S \right\rbrace$ is a set containing $S$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an arbitrary set $S$, the goal is to prove that $S$ is not an element of itself. The proposed proof proceeds by considering the set $T=\{S\}$, i.e., the set $T$ whose one and only member is the set $S$. Then $T$ is nonempty, because it has a member, namely $S$. So we can apply the axiom of regularity to conclude that $T$ has a member that has no members in common with $T$.  That member of $T$ is $S$, because $S$ is the only member of $T$. So $S$ has no members in common with $T$. Tbat is, no member of $T$ can also be a member of $S$. Well, $S$ is a member of $T$, so $S$ cannot be a member of $S$, q.e.d.

Comment: Dear Professor - Thanks you for your kind elucidation of the proof. It is the wonder of MSE that a professor such as yourself takes the time to to give their insight. Maybe I could impose a bit further as to my question regarding the use and omission of brackets. When you say "has a member, namely $S$," do you mean $S$ as a member of$\{S\}$? Yet where I am most confused is why is $T\bigcap S= \{S\}\bigcap S=\{S\}$, where the last $S$ is in brackets. With regards,

Comment: For the first question in your comment: Yes, $S$ is a member (in fact the one and only member) of $\{S\}$. The definition of the bracket notation for sets implies, in particular, that $\{a\}$ is the set whose only member is $a$; this holds regardless of what $a$ is.  For your second question: The first equality, $T\cap S=\{S\}\cap S$ is just because $T$ was defined to be $\{S\}$. For the second equality, consider what an arbitrary element, say $x$, of $\{S\}\cap S$ could be. It has to be an element of $\{S\}$, so it has to be $S$. And then it's also [continued in next comment]

Comment: an element of $S$ because the solution in your question began by assuming $S\in S$. So $\{S\}\cap S$ has exactly one element, namely $S$. That means that $\{S\}\cap S$  is the same set as $\{S\}$.

Comment: Note that, unlike the proof you quoted, the proof in my answer didn't proceed by contradiction.  So the statement $S\in S$ and other statements derived from it are available in the proof you quoted, but not in mine.

Comment: Dear Professor - It is with pleasure that I can give you this bounty to thank you for your patient and kind answers to my questions and your generous participation on this website. With best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Let $$E=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} $$

then
$$a\in \{a\} \subset \{a,b\} \in E $$